# T3 framework - Site structure with Mega Menu

Tags: joomla3.0, megamenu

I have T3 framework on my site (build by unreliable freelancer) and one of requested features was Mega Menu that is included in this framework. I have to use v. 1.2.1 because when I upgrade, I have problems with layout, javascript etc. so let's stay with this old version.

My problem is, that I realized that the site has no structure, all links are in root and that's because Mega Menu uses modules which show separate menus in them. I can fix site structure by moving all separate "sub" menus into main menu and create nice menu tree, I can modify modules to show only portion of menu, but when I do this, I get Mega Menu AND dropdown menu in same dropdown (2 rows, first is unwanted dropdown - classic menu, second row is full of menu modules that should be visible).

Can you please guide me, how to remove dropdown menu? Classic Menu has option to show only 1 level of menu, but I can't find something similar for Mega Menu :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked better into megamenu configuration in database and fixed the menu by removing unnecessary rows on top of submenus :)

I know that it's easy to edit megamenu in backend, but with 1.2.1 I'm getting error with paths to t3-assets etc. - well, this is fixed in 1.4.3 of course, but when I upgrade to 1.4.3, my menu is flickering (I don't want any slide/fade effects, just stay open while moving between menu items).

I had something like this:

```
{\"item-103\":{\"sub\":{\"rows\":[[{\"item\":342,\"width\":12}],[{\"position\":108,\"width\":4},{\"position\":107,\"width\":4},{\"position\":109,\"width\":4}]]}
```

and just removed unnecessary row to make it like this:

```
{\"item-103\":{\"sub\":{\"rows\":[[{\"position\":108,\"width\":4},{\"position\":107,\"width\":4},{\"position\":109,\"width\":4}]]}
```

but anyways, thanks for support